# Calling a C/assembly function from OCaml more directly than with caml_c_call

Tags: ocaml

OCaml allows C functions to be called from OCaml programs, as long as the programmer follows the instructions in the "Interfacing C with OCaml" chapter of the manual.

When following these instructions, a call to a C function is translated by the native compiler to:

```
    movq    ml_as_z_sub@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
    call    caml_c_call@PLT
```

(amd64 instruction set here, but looking at other architectures, the scheme seems to be rather uniform).

The function `caml_c_call` eventually does a computed jump `call    *%rax`, but it does a lot of things before and after. From asmrun/amd64.S:

```
/* Call a C function from Caml */

FUNCTION(G(caml_c_call))
.Lcaml_c_call:
    /* Record lowest stack address and return address */
        popq    %r12
        STORE_VAR(%r12, caml_last_return_address)
        STORE_VAR(%rsp, caml_bottom_of_stack)
    /* Make the exception handler and alloc ptr available to the C code */
        STORE_VAR(%r15, caml_young_ptr)
        STORE_VAR(%r14, caml_exception_pointer)
    /* Call the function (address in %rax) */
        call    *%rax
    /* Reload alloc ptr */
        LOAD_VAR(caml_young_ptr, %r15)
    /* Return to caller */
        pushq   %r12
        ret
```

When one wants to frequently execute a couple of instructions that neither allocate nor raise exceptions, the above is a little bit overkill.

Does anyone have any experience in calling a small assembly routine directly from OCaml, without going through the `caml_c_call` stub? This probably involves tricking the native compiler into thinking that it is calling an ML function, or modifying the compiler.

The question is in the context of the library Zarith, where small assembly bits of code could compute and return most results directly, without having to go through `caml_c_call`, and only jump to `caml_c_code` for the difficult arguments that require allocation or exceptions. See [this file](https://forge.ocamlcore.org/scm/viewvc.php/%2acheckout%2a/trunk/caml_z_x86_64.S?revision=42&root=zarith) for examples of assembly bits that could be executed directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe ["noalloc"](http://camltastic.blogspot.com/2008/08/tip-calling-c-functions-directly-with.html) and "float" could be of some use?

PS some more [related links](https://github.com/camlunity/kamlo_wiki/blob/master/bindings.md).

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you wouldn't mind the overhead of an OCaml function call if the function you were calling could be written in assembly.  I just did some experimentation, and you *can* do this by the method I outlined above.

Here's what I did.  To get a workable assembly language template, I defined a simple function in OCaml and compiled with the -S flag.

```
$ cat sep.ml
let addto x = x + 1
$ /usr/local/ocaml312/bin/ocamlopt -inline 0 -c -S sep.ml
```

*Note:* you need to specify `-inline 0` to assure that ocamlopt takes the code from your generated .o file and not from the inline definition in the .cmx file.

Now you have a file named sep.s.  The `addto` function looks like this (amazingly good
code, actually):

```
_camlSep__addto_1030:
.L100:
        addq    $2, %rax
        ret
```

Just for a test, I changed the 2 (which represents 1 in OCaml) to 4 (which represents 2 in OCaml).  So you now have:

```
_camlSep__addto_1030:
.L100:
        addq    $4, %rax
        ret
```

Now assemble this file, producing a deviant version of sep.o.

```
$ as -o sep.o sep.s
```

In essence, you have tricked ocamlopt into treating the code in sep.o as if it was coded in OCaml.  But you can write the code yourself in assembly (if you're careful not to violate any of the architectural assumptions).

You can link it into a main program and run it:

```
$ cat main.ml
let main () =
    Printf.printf "%d\n" (Sep.addto 19)

let () = main ()
$ /usr/local/ocaml312/bin/ocamlopt -o main sep.cmx main.ml
$ main
21
```

As you can see, it runs the modified assembly code.

You could follow this procedure to create any OCaml-callable functions in
assembly code.  As long as you don't mind the overhead of an OCaml function call, this approach might do what you want.

I don't know how this trickery will affect the handling of debugging and garbage collection, so I wouldn't try this with a function that does any allocations.

These tests were run on Mac OS X 10.6.8 using OCaml 3.12.0 (the stock 64-bit build).  When I run "as", I'm running the stock OS X assembler from Xcode 4.0.2, which uses x86_64 architecture by default.

Comment: This is exactly what I originally had in mind, but in ygrek's links were this one that shows that you can get almost the same think with the "noalloc" annotation for external functions: http://camltastic.blogspot.com/2008/08/tip-calling-c-functions-directly-with.html

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me it doesn't help to trick the compiler into thinking it's calling an OCaml function, unless you also trick it into inlining the call.  As far as I can tell by perusing sources, inlined functions are expressed in something called Ulambda code, which in turn contains primitives.  So this line of thinking, anyway, leads to adding primitives for your Zarith operations.  If you do that, you have a good (not at all tricky) solution, but it might be more work than you want to do.

For a really tricky approach, you could try post-processing the generated asm code to remove function calls and replace them with in-line code.  This kind of trick has been used many times.  It usually doesn't hold up for long, but it might be good enough for the short term.
To do this, you'd just give the OCaml compiler the name of a different assembler to run, one that does your modifications before assembling.

Comment: I didn't want to go into tangential considerations in my question, but I have also been experimenting with ocamlopt's -compact option recently. This option expands allocation instructions (a few of them, say 6 or 7) instead of using a call to the allocation routine. As it turns out, with -compact, my code is both smaller **and** faster. So yes, for Zarith's assembly snippets that are of a similar length, I would be happy just avoiding the stores and the computed jump, and wouldn't feel I'm missing out on inlining.

Comment: For a fairly quick test, you could write stub functions in OCaml and compile everything up.  Then at the last minute, replace the .o file with one you wrote yourself in assembly.  (Or you could just massage the generated .S file and assemble it.)  Then link everything together.  If it works, you can pair the .o and .cmx files, and to ocamlopt it looks like an ordinary separately compiled module (maybe some debug info would be wrong, though).  Or maybe this fails because ocamlopt does some checksumming to check consistency of .cmx and .o file?